# how to get current tab in jquery.easytabs.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `jquery.easytabs.js` and to select a certain tab I use

```
$("#tab-container").easytabs('select', '#nameTab');
```

But before selecting I would like to know which tab I'm in
does someone know how to do it?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#tab-container").easytabs('getSelected')
```

Actually, it does return the tab-container object itself.

Comment: You can check which tab has the class "active" and get it's ID

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `<ul>` and `<li>` - the standard tab navigation structure on the lines of:
**HTML:**

`<ul id="main-nav" class="tabs">
<li class="home"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li class="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="contact"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>`

Then you can easily look for class `active` on each tab and return it.
**Jquery Code**

```
$('ul#main-nav li').on('click', function() { 
     if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
          console.log($(this).attr('class'));
     }
});
```

you can also save it to a variable and do further manipulation:

```
    $('ul#main-nav li').on('click', function() { 
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
             var myTab = $(this).attr('class');
                if(myTab == "home active") {
                    //do stuff
                }
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check with jquery because the current tab will have the class 'active':

```
$("#tab-container .tab.active")
```

Answer (score 0):

At last  I've used javascript, this is my code:

```
var tab_active = window.location.hash.substr(1);
if (tab_active=="map"){
    moveTree('map');
}else if(tab_active==""){
    $("#tab-container").easytabs('select', '#map');
    moveTree('map');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript:

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs({uiTabs: true});

$('#tab-container')

  .bind('easytabs:before', function(id,val,t) 

      if(t.selector == "#tabs2"){

          alert("Selected tab 2");

      } 

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is helpful now, but I tried:

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs('active', "#<tabID>")
```

This is returning true, if that tab is active.